# Is it possible to use a fake projection in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, projection, srid

I'm creating a spatial table in PostGIS. My geometries are going to be abstract, not related to a real world. So I need some fake SRID. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Your question is really puzzling. What would be the issue on simply ignoring the SRS? If you don't want, you can omit it and it will automatically become WGS84. If it is not what you meant, please elaborate on the use case of such a *fake SRS*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your coordinates are not part of any spatial reference system, use `SRID=0`.

(Or if you have older PostGIS versions, this is `SRID=-1`)